# angular and async pipe typescript complains for null

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have the following container component

```
export class EventsComponent {
  data$: Observable<Data[]> = this.store.select(data);
  loading$: Observable<boolean> = this.store.select(loading);
}
```

And bind the observables via `| async` to the presentational component:

```
 <app-presentational 
   [rowData]="data$ | async" 
   [loading]="loading$ | async" 
   ...
```

```
export class PresentComponent {
  @Input()
  rowData: Data[];

  @Input()
  loading: boolean;
}
```

However, the TS compiler always complains that the async pipe may return null.

**Update**, this is the exact error i get

```
Type 'boolean | null' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.ngtsc(2322)
```

So do I really have to change all my `@Input()` to this?

```
export class PresentComponent {
  @Input()
  rowData: Data[] | null;

  @Input()
  loading: boolean | null;
}
```

Comment: I won't do that `boolean | null`, that looks not correct to solve your issue. What is the exact compiler error you get?

Comment: I'm not sure if ngrx supports something like this syntax `this.store.select<Data[]>(data);` to get a typed result. What you at least should be able to do is: `this.store.select(data) as Observable<Data[]>`

Comment: it is the async pipe which returns `boolean | null`, i think this is the issue here

Comment: How is the loading$ observable constructed? Does it have an initial value of true?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#strict-null-checks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As Angular docs points [**here**](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#strict-null-checks):

> There are two potential workarounds to the above issues:
>
> In the template, include the non-null assertion operator ! at the end
> of a nullable expression, such as <user-detail [user]="user!" />.
>
> In this example, the compiler disregards type incompatibilities in
> nullability, just as in TypeScript code. In the case of the async
> pipe, note that the expression needs to be wrapped in parentheses, as
> in <user-detail [user]="(user$ | async)!" />.
>
> Disable strict null checks in Angular templates completely.
>
> When strictTemplates is enabled, it is still possible to disable
> certain aspects of type checking. Setting the option
> strictNullInputTypes to false disables strict null checks within
> Angular templates. This flag applies for all components that are part
> of the application.

But, instead of using the non-null assertion operator or even disabling the Angular strict checks, you could either:

1. use nullish coalescing operator (`??`) - available in Angular 12+:

**TS**:

```
@Component({
  template: ``,
})
export class PresentationalComponent {
  @Input() loading: boolean;
  @Input() rowData: Data[];
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<app-presentational
  [loading]="(loading$ | async) ?? false"
  [rowData]="(rowData$ | async) ?? []"
></app-presentational>
```

2. use `ngAcceptInputType_*`:

**TS**:

```
@Component({
  template: ``,
})
export class PresentationalComponent {
  static ngAcceptInputType_loading?: boolean | null;
  // Note that if you have `@angular/cdk` installed you can use this instead:
  // static ngAcceptInputType_loading: BooleanInput;
  static ngAcceptInputType_rowData?: Data[] | null;

  @Input() loading: boolean;
  @Input() rowData: Data[];
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<app-presentational
  [rowData]="rowData$ | async"
  [loading]="loading$ | async"
></app-presentational>
```

3. [**TS 4.3+**](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-3/#separate-write-types): different types for `getter` and `setter`:

**TS**:

```
@Component({
  template: ``,
})
export class PresentationalComponent {
  @Input()
  // Note that if you have `@angular/cdk` installed you can use `BooleanInput` instead.
  set loading(loading: boolean | null | undefined) {
    this._loading = loading ?? false;
  }
  get loading(): boolean {
    return this._loading;
  }
  private _loading: Data[];

  @Input()
  set rowData(rowData: Data[] | null | undefined) {
    this.rowData = rowData ?? [];
  }
  get rowData(): Data[] {
    return this._rowData;
  }
  private _rowData: Data[] = [];
}
```

Note that nowadays you should prefer to use option 3 rather than the 2, as [`input setter coercion fields` are being deprecated](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/43506).

Comment: The last line in the solution #3 should be: `private _rowData: Data[] = [];`

Comment: This is gross... Angular could get their shtuff together. The main reason why this is happening is because if you have an empty observable Angular will render it as null.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code snippet as below. should fix null assignment error.

```
 <app-presentational 
   [rowData]="(data$ | async)!" 
   [loading]="(loading$ | async)!" 
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell from just the information you provided, but it looks the  component just needs null handling when the Observable hasn't provided a value

```html
<app-presentational 
  [rowData]="data$ | async" 
  [loading]="(loading$ | async) || false"
/>
```

Comment: Not sure if "(data$ | async) || []" is needed as the complier is only complaining about the boolean.

Answer (score -1):

Your Store State initialy is undefined that's why you getting null or you didn't declared the Store State object

1. try having initial values:

```
export class PresentComponent {
  @Input()
  rowData: Data[] = [];

  @Input()
  loading = false;
```

Also for .select you are selecting part of the state it works with strings:
try converting them to string

```
export class EventsComponent {
  data$: Observable<Data[]> = this.store.select('data');
  loading$: Observable<boolean> = this.store.select('loading');
```

you can also do with multiples when going inside objects in state.

```
this.store.select('name1', 'name2', ...)
```

2. But still it would be probably null because your initial state.
   You can try without the | async so this will never be null

```
export class EventsComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Data[] = [];
  loading = false;

  constructor(private store: Store<{ data: Data[], loading: boolean}>) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // you can do one by one
    this.store.select('data')
      .subscribe(next => this.data = next);

    this.store.select('loading')
      .subscribe(next => this.loading = next);

    // or do

    // all together
    this.store.subscribe(next => {
      this.data = next.data;
      this.loading = next.loading;
    });
  }
}
```